# Alexa skill with Spring boot not working

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to connect Alexa with Spring Boot webservice but I am facing few issues. servlet is not working only in the server and it throws 404 but in local I am getting 500 and 400 with the same URL I am using for servlet.

Application file

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentScan;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.amazon.speech.Sdk;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.SpeechletServlet;



@EnableCaching
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class VocabBrawlAlexaApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(VocabBrawlAlexaApplication.class.getName());



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("Info Message Logged !!!");
         //setAmazonProperties();

        SpringApplication.run(VocabBrawlAlexaApplication.class, args);
        LOGGER.info("Info Message Logged asdfsa !!!");
        setAmazonProperties();
    }

    /**
     * Sets system properties which are picked up by the {@link SpeechletServlet}.
     */
    private static void setAmazonProperties() {
        // Disable signature checks for development
        LOGGER.info("Info Message Logged setAmazonProperties !!!");
        System.setProperty(Sdk.DISABLE_REQUEST_SIGNATURE_CHECK_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");
        // Allow all application ids for development
        System.setProperty(Sdk.SUPPORTED_APPLICATION_IDS_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "**********");
        // Disable timestamp verification for development
        System.setProperty(Sdk.TIMESTAMP_TOLERANCE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "1500");
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean registerServlet() {

        LOGGER.info("Alexa configuration");

        SpeechletServlet speechletServlet = new SpeechletServlet();
        speechletServlet.setSpeechlet(new VocabBrawlSpeechlet());

        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(speechletServlet,"/hello");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("alexa");
        servletRegistrationBean.addUrlMappings("/alexa/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.addUrlMappings("/alexa/hello/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.addUrlMappings("/hello/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.addUrlMappings("/hello");
        servletRegistrationBean.addUrlMappings("/*");
        return servletRegistrationBean;     
    } 
}
```

Servlet file

```
package com.vocabBrawlAlexa;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.amazon.speech.json.SpeechletRequestEnvelope;
import com.amazon.speech.slu.Intent;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.IntentRequest;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.LaunchRequest;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SessionEndedRequest;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SessionStartedRequest;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletResponse;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletV2;
import com.amazon.speech.ui.OutputSpeech;
import com.amazon.speech.ui.PlainTextOutputSpeech;
import com.amazon.speech.ui.Reprompt;
import com.amazon.speech.ui.SimpleCard;
import com.vocabBrawlAlexa.service.IAlexaService;
import com.vocabBrawlAlexa.service.impl.AlexaServiceImpl;


@Service
public class VocabBrawlSpeechlet  implements SpeechletV2 {

    static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(VocabBrawlSpeechlet.class);


    private IAlexaService alexaService= new AlexaServiceImpl();
    @Override
    public void onSessionStarted(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<SessionStartedRequest> requestEnvelope) {
        log.info("onSessionStarted " );
        log.info("Request requestId "+requestEnvelope.getRequest().getRequestId()
                +" session Id "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getSessionId()+
                " user ID "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getUser().getUserId());        
        // any initialization logic goes here
    }

    @Override
    public SpeechletResponse onLaunch(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<LaunchRequest> requestEnvelope) {
        log.info("onLaunch");
        log.info("Request requestId "+requestEnvelope.getRequest().getRequestId()
                +" session Id "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getSessionId()+
                " user ID "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getUser().getUserId());
        return getWelcomeResponse();
    }

    @Override
    public SpeechletResponse onIntent(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<IntentRequest> requestEnvelope) {
        IntentRequest request = requestEnvelope.getRequest();
        log.debug("reached Intent");
        log.info("onIntent");
        log.info("Request requestId "+requestEnvelope.getRequest().getRequestId()
                +" session Id "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getSessionId()+
                " user ID "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getUser().getUserId());

        Intent intent = request.getIntent();
        String intentName = (intent != null) ? intent.getName() : null;

        if ("HelloWorldIntent".equals(intentName)) {
            log.debug("HelloWorldIntent Intent");
            log.debug(alexaService);
            //IAlexaService alexa = new AlexaServiceImpl();
            return alexaService.getHelloIntentResponse();
        } else if ("AMAZON.HelpIntent".equals(intentName)) {
            return getHelpResponse();
        } else {
            return getAskResponse("HelloWorld", "This is unsupported.  Please try something else.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionEnded(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<SessionEndedRequest> requestEnvelope) {
        log.info("onSessionEnded");
        log.info("Request requestId "+requestEnvelope.getRequest().getRequestId()
                +" session Id "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getSessionId()+
                " user ID "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getUser().getUserId());
        // any cleanup logic goes here
    }

    /**
     * Creates and returns a {@code SpeechletResponse} with a welcome message.
     *
     * @return SpeechletResponse spoken and visual response for the given intent
     */
    private SpeechletResponse getWelcomeResponse() {
        String speechText = "Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello";
        return getAskResponse("HelloWorld", speechText);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a {@code SpeechletResponse} for the hello intent.
     *
     * @return SpeechletResponse spoken and visual response for the given intent
     */
    private SpeechletResponse getHelloResponse() {
        log.debug("reached hello world");
        String speechText = "Hello world";

        // Create the Simple card content.
        SimpleCard card = getSimpleCard("HelloWorld", speechText);

        // Create the plain text output.
        PlainTextOutputSpeech speech = getPlainTextOutputSpeech(speechText);

        return SpeechletResponse.newTellResponse(speech, card);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a {@code SpeechletResponse} for the help intent.
     *
     * @return SpeechletResponse spoken and visual response for the given intent
     */
    private SpeechletResponse getHelpResponse() {
        String speechText = "You can say hello to me!";
        return getAskResponse("HelloWorld", speechText);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that creates a card object.
     * @param title title of the card
     * @param content body of the card
     * @return SimpleCard the display card to be sent along with the voice response.
     */
    private SimpleCard getSimpleCard(String title, String content) {
        SimpleCard card = new SimpleCard();
        card.setTitle(title);
        card.setContent(content);

        return card;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for retrieving an OutputSpeech object when given a string of TTS.
     * @param speechText the text that should be spoken out to the user.
     * @return an instance of SpeechOutput.
     */
    private PlainTextOutputSpeech getPlainTextOutputSpeech(String speechText) {
        PlainTextOutputSpeech speech = new PlainTextOutputSpeech();
        speech.setText(speechText);

        return speech;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that returns a reprompt object. This is used in Ask responses where you want
     * the user to be able to respond to your speech.
     * @param outputSpeech The OutputSpeech object that will be said once and repeated if necessary.
     * @return Reprompt instance.
     */
    private Reprompt getReprompt(OutputSpeech outputSpeech) {
        Reprompt reprompt = new Reprompt();
        reprompt.setOutputSpeech(outputSpeech);

        return reprompt;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for retrieving an Ask response with a simple card and reprompt included.
     * @param cardTitle Title of the card that you want displayed.
     * @param speechText speech text that will be spoken to the user.
     * @return the resulting card and speech text.
     */
    private SpeechletResponse getAskResponse(String cardTitle, String speechText) {
        SimpleCard card = getSimpleCard(cardTitle, speechText);
        PlainTextOutputSpeech speech = getPlainTextOutputSpeech(speechText);
        Reprompt reprompt = getReprompt(speech);

        return SpeechletResponse.newAskResponse(speech, reprompt, card);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "servlet is not working only in the server and it throws 404 but in local" ?

Specifically what is "the server" and what is "in local" ?

Comment: /hello is the URL for servlet. when I try this in local by hitting localhost:8080/local it's working. Then I tried after deploying the project in server and hit example.com/Alexa/hello it's giving me 404. I tried other possible URLs also like example.com/hello etc.,

Comment: What server are you deploying it to ?

Comment: I am deploying this to Go Daddy Virtual private server.

Comment: can u upload logs from cloudwatch in your question

Comment: I am not deploying this as lambda function. I am deploying this as webservice in our Go daddy VPS. Since it's 404 we are not getting any error logs also :(

Answer (score 0):

Please call `setAmazonProperties()` method before `SpringApplication.run(VocabBrawlAlexaApplication.class, args);`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("Info Message Logged !!!");
        setAmazonProperties();
        SpringApplication.run(VocabBrawlAlexaApplication.class, args);
        LOGGER.info("Info Message Logged asdfsa !!!");
    }
```